# Why is the character value sum of roots of unity?

Tags: representation-theory

I know that every finite representation is equivalent to a unitary representation if we choose a proper inner product("averaging") for the underlying vector space. Also, each element of unitary representation is a unitary matrix and the unitary matrix is unitarily diagonalizable.
But what does this tell us about the character value(trace of this matrix), in particular, why does it have to be the sum of roots of unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ be a complex representation of a finite group $G$.  Then if $g \in G$, there is some $k$ (the order of $g$) that $g^k = e$, the group identity.  Then if $M = \rho(g)$, then $M^k = \rho(g)^k = \rho(g^k) = \rho(e) = I$ where $I \in GL(V)$ is the identity.  So the minimal polynomial of $M$ must divide $x^k - 1$.  It follows that every eigenvalue of $M$ is a root of unity, and the trace of $M$ is the sum of the eigenvalues, hence a sum of roots of unity.

Another, more direct proof:

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $\rho(g)$ and let $k$ be the order of $g$.  Then there is $v$ so that $\rho(g)v = \lambda v$.  Then $\rho(g^k)(v) = \rho(e)(v) = Iv = v$, and also $\rho(g^k)(v) = \rho(g)^k v = \lambda^k v$.  It follows that $\lambda^k = 1$.  So all eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$ are roots of unity, and hence the trace of $\rho$ is a sum of roots of unity.

Comment: Thank you so much. I probably missed something big here. Is it a well-known fact that eigenvalue is a root of minimal polynomial? I know it's a root of characteristic polynomial  by definition...

Comment: Yup, the eigenvalues of the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomials are the same (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra))) - only the multiplicities are different.

Comment: @Min: an eigenvalue, by definition, is a scalar $\lambda$ such that there exists some eigenvector $v$ such that $gv = \lambda v$. If $f(t)$ is any polynomial such that $f(g) = 0$ (it doesn't matter which) this gives $f(g) v = f(\lambda) v = 0$, so $f(\lambda) = 0$. In this case $g^k = e$ immediately gives $g^k v = \lambda^k v = v$ so $\lambda^k = 1$, there's no need to even reason explicitly about the minimal or characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Oh, I see. So minimal polynomial not just divides character polynomial. They have the same roots. Thank you!

Comment: @MinSeokSong I've added another proof that doesn't make use of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: * The above should be "the roots of the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial are the same".